# Clip to bounds a particular view within a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

### Problem

I have a custom UIView that has an image and selection (border) subview. I want to be able to add this custom UIView as a subview of a larger blank view. Here's the catch, the larger blank view needs to clip all of the subviews to its bounds (`clipToBounds`). However, the user can select one of the custom UIViews within the large blank view, where the subview is then highlighted by a border.

*The problem is that because the large blank view clips to bounds, the outline for the selected subview is cut off.*

I want the image in the subview to clip to the bounds of the large blank view, but still be able to see the full selection outline of the subview (which is cut off due to the large blank view's corner radius.

*I am using UIKit and Swift*

**What I Currently Have:**
[image]

**What I Want:**
[image]

> The image part of the subview clips to the bounds (corner radius) of the large blank view, but the outline selection view in the subview should not.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Can't you apple the border to the container view, the one you call the `the large blank view` holding everything within it ?

Comment: No, you need to be able to select the individual subviews in the parent view - I have already built this out and the result is that when you tap on a subview, a border is added to show which subview is currently selected. The problem I'm having is that I need to be able for the image in the subview to clip to the bounds of the parent view, but the border should not clip to the bounds of the parent view (ie. the image in the subview is clipped by the corner radius of the parent view, but the border for the subview should not be).

Comment: So do I understand your hierarchy right: **MainView** contains multiple **custom subviews**. Inside **custom subview** you have an **imageView**. **MainView** clips to bounds and you need to be able to show selection of **custom subviews** within the **MainView**

Comment: Yes. I have already setup the selection process for the subviews. When a subview is selected, it is given a border. My MainView has a corner radius with clipsToBounds set to true so that all subviews stay within the bounds of the MainView. However, I only want the image in each subview to be masked by the MainView's corner radius. On the contrary, the border for each subview should ignore the clip to bounds. Refer to the images - image 1 shows MainView's clipToBounds cutting the border for the subview (I only want MainView's clipToBounds applied to the subview image).

Comment: @EuanTraynor - this is a little confusing... are you saying you have a view with rounded corners, with `.clipsToBounds = true`, and some subviews, like this (top one has `.clipsToBounds = false`) https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVbgS.png --- and when you "select" the subviews, you want it to "highlight" them like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCoL7.png ?

Comment: That is exactly what I want - I want to achieve what you have in the second image on the bottom view. How did you do that?

Comment: @EuanTraynor - I did that by adding an "outline view" to the controller. When a subview is the "clipped rounded corner" view is tapped, we tell the controller, and the controller shows and positions the "outline view." Depending on exactly what you need, that may or may not be a good solution. Can you describe a bit more what you're trying to do? For example, are you dynamically adding subviews to the clipping view? And, what do you want to do when a subview is selected (other than highlighting it)?

Comment: I want to achieve exactly what you have done on the bottom view of this [image](i.stack.imgur.com/dCoL7.png). The image in the subview should clip to the bounds of the parent view which has a corner radius. When a user selects on one of the subviews, an outline should appear around the subview, but it should extend beyond the parent view and should not abide by the parent view's clip to bounds. When a subview is selected, it allows the user to move the subview around and change the image.

Comment: @EuanTraynor - I'll post an example for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is not technically possible as [defined by the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds)

From the docs:

**clipsToBounds**

*Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the **receiver**. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is false.*

So the subviews do not have control of whether they get clipped or not, it's the container view that decides.

So I believe Matic's answer is right in that the structure he proposes gives you the most flexibility.

With that being said, here are a couple of work arounds I can think of:

**First, set up to recreated your scenario**

Custom UIView

```
// Simple custom UIView with image view and selection UIView
fileprivate class CustomBorderView: UIView
{
    private var isSelected = false
    {
        willSet
        {
            toggleBorder(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var selectionView = UIView()
    
    init()
    {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        configureImageView()
        configureSelectionView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    
    private func configureImageView()
    {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image-test")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(imageView)
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func configureSelectionView()
    {
        selectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        selectionView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        selectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        addSubview(selectionView)
        
        selectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        selectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        selectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        selectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        selectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        configureTapGestureRecognizer()
    }
    
    private func configureTapGestureRecognizer()
    {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                action: #selector(didTapSelectionView))
        selectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc
    private func didTapSelectionView()
    {
        isSelected = !isSelected
    }
    
    private func toggleBorder(_ on: Bool)
    {
        if on
        {
            selectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 28.0/255.0,
                                                      green: 244.0/255.0,
                                                      blue: 162.0/255.0,
                                                      alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            
            return
        }
        
        selectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }
}
```

Then in the view controller

```
class ClippingTestViewController: UIViewController
{
    private let mainContainerView = UIView()
    private let customView = CustomBorderView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Clipping view"
        configureMainContainerView()
        configureCustomBorderView()
        
        mainContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        mainContainerView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    private func configureMainContainerView()
    {
        mainContainerView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(mainContainerView)
        
        mainContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        mainContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,
                                                   constant: 20).isActive = true
        
        mainContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                               constant: 20).isActive = true
        
        mainContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,
                                                    constant: -20).isActive = true
        
        mainContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    private func configureCustomBorderView()
    {
        mainContainerView.addSubview(customView)
        
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        customView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This gives me your current experience

[image: clipToBounds custom UIView with border cornerRadius]

**Work Around 1. - Shrink subviews on selection**

When the view is not selected, everything looks fine. When the view is selected, you could reduce the width and height of the custom subview with some animation while adding the border.

**Work Around 2. - Manually clip desired subviews**

You go through each subview in your container view and:

- Apply the clipping to any subview you desire
- Apply the corner radius to the views you clip
- Leaving the container view unclipped and without a corner radius

To do that, I created a custom UIView subclass for the container view

```
class ClippingSubView: UIView
{
    override var clipsToBounds: Bool
    {
        didSet
        {
            if clipsToBounds
            {
                clipsToBounds = false
                clipImageViews(in: self)
                layer.cornerRadius = 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Recursively go through all subviews
    private func clipImageViews(in view: UIView)
    {
        for subview in view.subviews
        {
            // I am only checking image view, you could check which you want
            if subview is UIImageView
            {
                print(layer.cornerRadius)
                subview.layer.cornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
                subview.clipsToBounds = true
            }
            
            clipImageViews(in: subview)
        }
    }
}
```

Then make sure to adjust the following lines where you create your views:

```
let mainContainerView = ClippingSubView()

// Do this only after you have added all the subviews for this to work
mainContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
mainContainerView.clipsToBounds = true
```

This gives me your desired output

[image: UIView clipToBounds custom UIView UIImageView with border cornerRadius]

Comment: The only problem with this is that the subview has its own independent corner radius - if the subview corner radius is 0, then it goes out of the main view's bounds (extends beyond the corner radius). The subview image should clip to the bounds of the main view and not extend outside of the corner radius, whereas, the border should. See the following [GIF](https://ibb.co/sP56Tfw)

Comment: As I said, it's a work around, not a solution to your problem. You will have to change something in your view hierarchy because what you are asking for changing the implementation of `clipsToBounds`. In my opinion, either the main container view does not clip and you give the corner radius and clipping to subviews OR you have resize views. I will dissuade you from the later because that is a LOT of work when it is much more simpler to get the output you want with a slight change in which views clip and which do not. However, keep looking, you might find something better - good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem which may have multiple solutions. In the end though I always find it best to simply go one level higher:

```
ContainerView (Does not clip)
    ContentView (Clips)
    HighlightingView (Does not clip)
```

You would put all your current views on `ContentView`. Then introduce another view which represents your selection and put it on the same level as your `ContentView`.

In the end this will give you most flexibility. It can still get a bit more complicated when you add things like shadows. But again "more views" is usually the end solution.

Comment: This is what it currently looks like: `MainView > SubView > Image and SelectionView`. The `Image` needs to clip to the bounds of `MainView`, and the `SelectionView` should not clip to the bounds of `MainView`. I want to use the `SelectionView` in the `SubView`, rather than having a single `SelectionView` in the `MainView` (that changes and moves to the same location as the selected subview because I have a lot of working components that will keep being moved and change frame.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely run into a lot of problems trying to get a subview's border to display outside its superView's clipping bounds.

One approach is to add an "Outline View" as a sibling of the "Clipping View":

[image]

When you select a clippingView's subview - and drag it around - set the frame of the outlineView to match the frame of that subview.

You'll want to set `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on the outlineView so it doesn't interfere with touches on the subviews.